# I am not able down to use 'Scroll Down' keyword on robot framework for mobile automation, as the element is located at end of the page

Tags: automation, appium, robotframework

I am not able down to use 'Scroll Down' keyword on robot framework for mobile automation, as the element is located at end of the page

When I use Scroll down, the terminal shows exception error and the actual element is not found as it is located at the end of the page

```
*** Settings ***
Library    AppiumLibrary

*** Variables ***

${Android_Deny_Button} =  //android.widget.Button[@text="Deny"]
${RecyclerView_Button} =  //android.widget.ImageButton[@content-desc="Login"]
${Login/Signup} =   //android.widget.TextView[@text="Log in or sign up"]
${Android_Accept&Continue} =    //android.widget.Button["ACCEPT & CONTINUE"]
${Android_No Thanks} =    //android.widget.Button["NO THANKS"]
${Email_Field} =    //android.widget.EditText[@text="Email address"]
${Password_Field} =    //android.widget.EditText[@text="Password"]
${Login_Button} =    //android.widget.Button[@content-desc="Log in"]
${Signup_Element1} =    //android.widget.TextView[@text="Sign up now" and @index="0"]
${firstname} =  //android.view.View[@index="5"]//android.widget.EditText[@index="0"]
${Signupnow} =    //android.view.View[@content-desc="Sign up now"]//android.widget.TextView[@text="Sign up now"]




*** Test Cases ***
Open_Application
      Open Application      http://localhost:4723/wd/hub     platformName=Android    platformVersion=11     deviceName=emulator-5554    appPackage=de.quandoo.android.consumerapp     appActivity=com.quandoo.consumer.legacy.ui.general.SplashScreenActivity       automationName=Uiautomator2
           
      sleep    8
      click element    ${Android_Deny_Button}
      Wait until page contains element    ${RecyclerView_Button}      7
      
      Click Element    ${RecyclerView_Button}
      sleep      5
      Click Element    ${Login/Signup} 
      sleep     2
      Click Element    //android.widget.Image[@index="0"]
      sleep     2
      
      Scroll Down    //android.view.View[@content-desc="Sign up now"]
      sleep     5
      Click Element         //android.view.View[@content-desc="Sign up now"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using following keyword:

```
Scroll Element Into View          locator
```

Scrolls the element identified by locator into view. More details at: [Link to Doc](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Scroll%20Element%20Into%20View)

Comment: Thanks, but I am working on Mobile automation where I need appium KW's

Answer (score 0):

Try this keyword:

`Swipe By Percent     start_x   start_y   end_x   end_y`